# Adding a Xerox Printer to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, printing, ip, xerox

Good Morning,

I am trying to add a Xerox 7125 printer to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have downloaded and extracted the PPD from Xerox's Website, which is just a generic PPD, I added the printer by IP and added the PPD, but it just prints 1 page with ghostscript error then continues to print blank pages indefinitely until the job is cancelled from the printer. This happens regardless of what i print, Google homepage from firefox, pdf, text file... anything.

Even if i add a printer shared from a windows machine it still asks for a driver.

Are there any suggestions I could try to see if i can get it working?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the link to the download.

Comment: http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-7120/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en there are 2 downloads, the second larger one has specific ppds I used the 7120 ppd as that is a similar model printer with similar functionality.  But it makes no difference

Comment: Also, I reached out to my local xerox supplier who kindly supplied me with a postscript module for the printer, this is installed and tested with a mac so i know it works. but the linux pc still fails to print correctly.

I get a page that starts with the error ps-adobe-3.0 creator gpl ghostscript 9

Comment: This question/answer helped me set up XSA (Xerox Standard Accounting) by editing the ppd file.  This solved the problem of "invalid accounting codes" Error Notice when trying to print.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install one **Xerox Workcentre 7120** on Ubuntu 16.04 without any downloads from Xerox. Xerox’s PPD does not support XSA User Based Accounting. I need it to print to a shared printer, where each user has is own code.

These instructions works for users with XSA or not, since XSA can be disabled in the printer’s options.

I’ve downloaded the PPD from: https://bitbucket.org/josebagar/xerox_workcentre_7120/raw/0e6c0d7788f3aa11f8bcc58ab224a259dbf0e8f2/printer.ppd

I’ve changed `XXXXYOURPASSWORDHEREXXXX` to my personal code and stored the ppd on `/etc/cups/ppd/` folder.

To configure the printer, I added a new printer, let it discover network printers, and selected the Xerox Workcentre 7120. The URI used was: `socket://192.168.0.20:9100` (my printer has the IP `192.168.0.20`).

I’ve choosed a custom PPD and selected the one just saved in `/etc/cups/ppd/`.

[image: Xerox Workcentre 7120 on Ubuntu 16.04]

The printer works perfect! The XSA accounting appears as an option.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - actually you've solved much of my time, as recently I was printing mostly via the web interface. I acknowledge it works (still) with Ubuntu 19.04. Interestingly, we use a configuration where there are user IDs and one group (all users share the same group) and it works when providing user ID only in the PPD (group ID is somehow automatically pulled) that is so much different when configuring driver in Windows where you need to provide both.

Answer (score 0):

This solution by @estibordo worked for me too, with the Xerox WorkCentre 7845 and Ubuntu 18.04.  When I first set up the printer, I had the default ppd file at `/etc/cups/ppd/WorkCentre-7845.ppd`.  I edited this file between the following two lines

```
*CloseGroup: PrintoutMode


*% Generic boilerplate PPD stuff as standard PostScript fonts and so on
```

adding the following block from the ppd file @estibordo linked to:

```
*% Generic Accounting
*JCLOpenUI *JCLAccounting/Accounting: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10.1 JCLSetup *JCLAccounting
*DefaultJCLAccounting: XSAUser
*JCLAccounting XSADisabled/Disabled: ""
*JCLAccounting XSAUser/XSA User Based Accounting: "@PJL XCPT <3C>?xml version=<22>1.0<22> encoding=<22>UTF-8<22>?<3E>
@PJL XCPT <3C>!DOCTYPE xpif SYSTEM <22>xpif-v02074.dtd<22><3E>
@PJL XCPT <3C>xpif version=<22>1.0<22> cpss-version=<22>2.07<22> xml:lang=<22>en-US<22><3E>
@PJL XCPT          <3C>job-template-attributes<3E>
@PJL XCPT              <3C>client-default-attributes-col syntax=<22>collection<22><3E>
@PJL XCPT                  <3C>job-accounting-user-id syntax=<22>name<22> xml:space=<22>preserve<22><3E>XXXXYOURPASSWORDHEREXXXX<3C>/job-accounting-user-id<3E>
@PJL XCPT                  <3C>job-accounting-user-passcode syntax=<22>octetString<22><3E><3C>/job-accounting-user-passcode<3E>
@PJL XCPT                  <3C>job-accounting-user-passcode-encryption syntax=<22>keyword<22><3E>xerox-simple-1<3C>/job-accounting-user-passcode-encryption<3E>
@PJL XCPT                  <3C>job-billing-passcode-encryption syntax=<22>keyword<22><3E>xerox-simple-1<3C>/job-billing-passcode-encryption<3E>
@PJL XCPT              <3C>/client-default-attributes-col<3E>
@PJL XCPT          <3C>/job-template-attributes<3E>
@PJL XCPT <3C>/xpif<3E>
"
*JCLCloseUI: *JCLAccounting
```

And, as he says, I replaced `XXXXYOURPASSWORDHEREXXXX` with my accounting code.  Worked like a charm!!