# Xerox workcentre 7835

Tags: networking, drivers, windows, printing, xerox

I have some printers on a Windows network and am trying to print from Ubuntu to these printers. The printer are all a Xerox Workcentre 7835. Installing the printer from the Ubuntu menu seems to work. After adding the printer I even get notifications about toner level/ paper shortage etc. But users who want to print should be ask for a code in order to print. After trying several drivers the result is every-time the same: the printer is detected and the  job seems to be accepted without entering a code, but eventually the printer doesn't accept the job and prints a error page about a wrong authorization code.

Downloading the Xerox drivers from their website doesn't work either. Same result as when adding the printer by the ubuntu printer setup

Does anybody know the solution on how to get the printer working on Ubuntu? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the ppd file to make this work.  Full details are given in the answers to [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879327/adding-a-xerox-printer-to-ubuntu-16-04).